# Index has not been initialized error on Sitecore 8.2 with Azure Search

Tags: azure, azure-search

I have `Sitecore 8.2 update 5` in `Azure PaaS` using Azure Search. When I am trying to open the content editor, it is throwing exception `Index has not been initialized` with stack trace info mentioning cloud search provider.

I tried the rebuilding index which completed without adding any item to any index.
Can anyone suggest what are the places I need to check?

Comment: Please share the exception details on your question, it will help triage your issue better

Comment: https://www.robhabraken.nl/index.php/3403/where-did-our-search-go/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[You need to upgrade to TLS 1.2](http://status.cloud.sitecore.net/maintenance/402e570b-2199-4336-886c-78f81b900ca0)

[For .Net Framework version 3.5 – 4.5.2 (Sitecore 8.2) explicit setting of TLS version is required.](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/688903)

> Microsoft Azure is upgrading platform TLS libraries and support for
>   TLS 1.2 is becoming the standard default. Sitecore customers running a
>   Sitecore version prior to 9.0 may experience communication errors
>   between Azure services, notably Azure Search. This can prevent
>   Sitecore from completing routine query and index operations with Azure
>   Search and cause a variety of complications.
>
> On February 26th, Microsoft started rollout of Azure Search with
>   enforce TLS 1.2 in use. Rollout started from US regions. Cloud Ops
>   team is monitoring situation, however, recommended solution for
>   customers is to apply the workaround described in KB article referred
>   above.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark. This saved our day :) .